# In darcs, how to view only the names of changed files

Tags: version-control, darcs

The command `$ darcs whatsnew` lists unrecorded changes in the working tree. However, often the full list of changes is too cluttered to see in one screen which files have changed.

**How can I list only the names of changed files?**

In `git` I do this via `$ git diff --name-only`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`darcs whatsnew -ls` should work I think