# Darcs list names of all tracked files

Tags: darcs

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939963/in-darcs-how-to-view-only-the-names-of-changed-files) answers how, in darcs, to list the names of added files with unrecorded changes.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/429693/git-list-all-files-currently-under-source-control) answers how, in git, to list the names of all files currently under source control.

How, in darcs, does one list the names of all files currently under source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing all indexed files is done with:

```
darcs show files
```

It may be helpful to know, that there are help-instructions available on the commandline. You can display them with `darcs help` and for every listed subcommand there are more help-instructions, which you can display by appending `help` to the subcommand. So, in this example with the subcomand `show`, that would be `darcs show help`.

Last but not least, there is avery good documentatioin with examples on
https://darcsbook.acmelabs.space/index.html